# `tee` for commands

Tags: shell-script, io-redirection, coreutils, tee, xsel

`tee` can redirect the piped standard input into the standard output **and** file.

```
echo Hello, World! | tee greeting.txt
```

The command above would display the greeting on the terminal screen and save it in the contents of `greeting.txt` file, creating the file if there's none by that name.

There's also `-a` switch for `tee` to append to the existing file instead of overwriting.

---

Is there a convenient way to redirect the piped input to the command and **standard output** instead of file?

I am trying to create a wrapper script for [`buku`](https://github.com/jarun/Buku) to copy to primary selection the URL of the bookmark specified by its index number.

```
# bukuc:
#!/bin/sh
url=$(buku -f 1 -p $1 | cut -f 2) # NUMBER : URL
echo $url # DISPLAY
echo $url | xsel # PRIMARY SELECTION
```

Here I use `echo` **two** times, first for displaying on the terminal, and then saving in the primary selection (clipboard).

I imagine something of `echo $url | teeC xsel` or a shortcut to display the output before passing to the next command (chaining commands), what would allow me to chain the whole command in one line without the need to save the result in a **variable** as follows:

```
buku -f 1 -p $1 | cut -f 2 | teeC xsel
```

---

I can also use it with [`urlview`](https://github.com/sigpipe/urlview) to view, select, and open with the `$BROWSER` as follows:

```
bukuc 10-20 | urlview
```

Comment: Try `tee /dev/tty` or `tty0` (dont remember exactly ... i am on the road)

Comment: `info tee` mentions process substitution, and pipe tee's output to a program...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's straightforward in shells that support [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution), e.g. bash

```
$ echo foo | tee >(xsel)
foo
$ xsel -o
foo
```

Otherwise, you could use a FIFO (although it lacks convenience)

```
$ mkfifo _myfifo
$ xsel < _myfifo &
$ echo bar | tee _myfifo
bar
$ xsel -o
bar
[1] + Done                       xsel 0<_myfifo
$
```

Comment: Thanks! Two things I noted: 1. `sh` (Bourne shell) doesn't support that feature; 2. The arrow has to stick as a part of the single operator `>()` for process substitution.

Answer (score 12):

The direct analogue of "tee for commands" is the [`pee` command from moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/) (`tee`, but with pipes). Its arguments are used as commands to run, not as paths, and they get the input piped to them rather than written to file. All of the commands are given the standard input you piped to `pee` as their own.

Using `pee`, you can get the result you wanted by telling it to run both `xsel` and `cat` with the input.

```
echo foo | pee xsel cat
```

There is an extra `cat` process floating around there to do the output, which isn't really a problem for your use case but could be less ideal other times. This works with any shell, unlike process substitution, but of course it does require an extra (probably less-common) tool installed.

You can give more complex commands by quoting them: `pee "xsel --display :1" cat`. They're run with `sh`, so you do have to be careful about shell metacharacters.

Comment: Very cool - didn't know about that

Comment: That's... not a good name.

Comment: As of today, it is available as a tarball, packaged for `apt` as a Debian package, so ... available to Ubuntu users in particular, but not available in AUR to `pacman` users. Last commit to the Github repo https://github.com/stigtsp/moreutils is 2 years old.