# How output one command with tee to standard ouput and also to pipe it to another command?

Tags: bash, process, pipe, command-substitution

Maybe this is duplicate, I have not found any answers though, but how to use pipe to output one command to multiple outpus (e.g. send it to pipe, stdout, or command substitution)?

I have this line:

```
$ command_with_output1 | tee >(command_with_output2) | command3
```

And I would like to send output from `command_with_output1` to `stdout` via `tee` and also to `command_with_output2` via `>()` and also to `command3` via `|`. Is it possible? How to achieve this?

A nonsensical exmaple ,but to demostrate what i meant, could be as follow:

1. pipe problem

   ```
   $ cat <<< "abc" | tee >( > /dev/null) | while read i; do echo "$i"; done
   ```

This command should output 2 times "abc" (1. - `tee`, 2. - `while read...`), but instead output just one:

```
user@host:~$ cat <<< "abc"| tee >( > /dev/null) | while read i; do echo $i; done
abc #only one, I would expect one more
```

Therefor I think, the second missing ouput will be "lost" after pipe (pipe won't deliver `stdout` from `tee` to `stdin` of `while`), because `tee` probably only works only on files, no pipes (correct me if I am wrong here).

2. stdout deliver probelm

   ```
   cat <<< "abc" | tee >(xargs -I{} bash -c "for i in '{}'; do echo $i; done")
   ```

Although this command does not use pipe "after" `tee`, I would also expect to output 2 times "abc" (again `tee`, and now `for i in ...`), but yet, outputs only once:

```
user@Host:~$ cat <<< "abc" | tee >(xargs -I{} bash -c "for i in '{}'; do echo $i; done")
abc #only one, I would expect one more
```

So to explain: in first command, whether am I right in that, `tee` does not output to pipe (but rather to file). And for the second command explain, why does not output 2 times, why does not the `xargs` command deliver the output via `'{}'` to `bash`

Comment: Why aren't you using an additional process substitution for `command3` with `tee`?

Comment: Because, the third command is more complicated and have more piped, at the end. But still, without any substitution, tee will not output to `stdout`  (e.g. `cmd1 | tee | cmd2`)

Comment: There's also`pee`, which is a [`tee` for commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/371730/65304)

Comment: Maybe you could show a more real example and also clarify where the final outputs should go?

Comment: @Kusalananda editted

Comment: @Herdsman if by `stdout` you mean "the terminal" you can just add `/dev/tty` to the `tee`

Comment: Your first command explicitly discards one copy of `abc`. You second command expands `$i` in the _calling_ shell, not in the `bash -c` shell.  That command should also look like `xargs -I {} bash -c 'for i do echo "$i"; done' bash {}` or simply `xargs -I {} bash -c 'printf "%s\n" "$@"' bash {}`.

Comment: 1) so explicilty `discard` you mean because of the pipe instead of file? That is what I thought. 2) that does not work, `echo "abc" | tee >(xargs -I {} bash -c 'printf "%s\n" "$@"' bash {})`, please send full command

Comment: @Herdsman 1) No you use `tee >( >/dev/null )`. You can't expect that to produce any output apart from what is sent on the the next part of the pipeline. 2) In what way does it not work. It produces `abc` twice. Once as the output of `tee`, and once as the output of `bash -c`.

Answer (score 1):

To explain your *pipe problem*:

Let's break it down into smaller chunks:

***$ cat <<< "abc"*** --> This command passes the string "abc" to the standard input of the command on the left, which is ***cat***.

***| tee >( > /dev/null)*** --> The ***tee*** command takes its input from the command ***cat*** by reading the standard input, passes the file-output to /dev/null and then writes the string "abc" to standard output.

**| while read i; do echo "$i"; done** --> The **read** command reads the string "abc" from standard input and stores the string "abc" to the variable ***i*** and then your loop prints the contents of ***i*** which is the string "abc" - and only once.

The ***tee*** command prints nothing on the terminal because its output is piped to the ***read*** command.

You can try this with writing the standard output to a file instead.

```
user@host:~$ cat <<< "abc"| tee file_name.txt | while read i; do echo $i >> file_name.txt; done; cat file_name.txt
```