# What is the correct way to pipe the same stream to multiple commands

Tags: bash, pipe

I have used this simple form with partial success:

$ command1 | (command2; command3; command4...)

But this fails in some cases. For example:

```
$ seq 100 | (head -10; echo "done") # works fine
$ seq 100 | (head -10; echo "done"; tail -10) # ignores tail
$ seq 1863 | (head -5 ; tail -10) # fails to print the last 10 lines
1
2
3
4
5

1861
1862
1863
```

Though any ideas on why these failures occur are welcome, I am mainly interested in the right way to pass the same input to multiple commands.

Comment: So... like a [`tee` for commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371699/tee-for-commands) ?

Comment: See [Command to display first few and last few lines of a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/66417)

Comment: Can you install a small utility? I know a tool designed for this, but will have to look it up. Going out now. will chk back later.

Comment: Buffering of stdio makes something like this unreliable.   If you are trying to feed pieces of the output to sequential commands with no gaps, it won't work.  If you are trying to send the same output to all three commands, you have to do it differently than this.  I recall other answers that explained why, at least one linked in above comments.